# How to use file_exists with autoload

Tags: php, require, file-exists, spl-autoload-register

I'm trying to use the spl_autoload_register function to autoload my classes.  I have got it to work but am still receiving a ton of warning messages like this: "Warning: include_once(application/models/controller.class.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in..."

I know I need to use file_exists method to fix this somehow but am not sure how to include this in my code:

```
    <?php

function myLoad($class) {
  include_once('application/controllers/'.$class.'.class.php');
  include_once('application/models/'.$class.'.class.php');
  include_once('application/'.$class.'.class.php');

}

spl_autoload_register('myLoad');

  new controller();


 ?>
```

I changed it to this and it is working now, but is there an easier/more concise way to do this? It seems sort of repetitive

```
function myLoad($class) {

  if (file_exists('application/controllers/'.$class.'.class.php')){
    include_once('application/controllers/'.$class.'.class.php');
  }
  if (file_exists('application/models/'.$class.'.class.php')){
    include_once('application/models/'.$class.'.class.php');
  }
  if (file_exists('application/'.$class.'.class.php')){
    include_once('application/'.$class.'.class.php');
  }
}

spl_autoload_register('myLoad');
```

Comment: Do you know `if()` instruction? use it before `include_once`.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but would I need to do that for each separate includes statement?  or is there an easier way to do them all at once?

Comment: Since your paths vary, its best to do it for each.

Comment: yes, you must check all alternatives is file exists

Comment: ah, okay. Thank you

Comment: Note that this might be a bit slow. Have you considered following PSR-4? Most PHP developers have converged on that standard for organizing classes in directories. the `.class.php` pattern is something that was more common 15 years ago. (I was about to say 10 years, but then I did the math and even Zend Framework was around back then and didn't do that anymore).

Comment: You may consider using composer for this (if it's not overkill for your needs):  https://getcomposer.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix these kinds of problem I like to enumerate over an anonymous array:

```
function myLoad($class) {
  foreach(['controllers', 'models', ''] as $prefix) {
    if(file_exists("application/$prefix/$class.class.php"))
      include_once("application/$prefix/$class.class.php");
  }
}

spl_autoload_register('myLoad');
```

Note that if you put the string like that, you'll have a double slash for the case where there's no prefix, but that shouldn't make a difference.
I find it more readable like that.

Comment: Thanks, I like this solution.  The double slash wouldn't affect the path though?

Comment: If you're going to give the path to a system command, the system is going to ignore double slashes. It would've been a real problem if you were giving the path to some parser function from a given library

Answer (score 1):

Using a loop is one of the way to make this more concise.  Put all the possibilities into an array, loop through the array, and return once a file is included.  In this case, the first item found is what will be used.

```
$paths = [
  'application/controllers/'.$class.'.class.php',
  'application/models/'.$class.'.class.php',
  'application/'.$class.'.class.php'
];

foreach($paths as $path) {
   if (file_exists($path)) {
      include_once($path);
      return;
   }
}
```

However, instead of building your own autoloader, I recommend looking at the PSR-4 standard and utilizing composer.